# Can't find tagged Azure resource group with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, automation

I have tagged my azure resource groups based on environments.

Now I'am trying to do some automation on the test environments and I want to retrieve all resource groups tagged with Env=test.

I found this line here (https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/)

```
   $testRg= Find-AzureRmResourceGroup -Tag @{ Name="Env"; Value="Test" } | %{ $_.Name }
```

The problem is that this doesn't return anything.

Then i tried to tag a single resource with the same tag and that worked with this line:

```
$testR= Find-AzureRmResource -TagName Env -TagValue Test| %{ $_.ResourceName }
```

Anyone experienced this or know what I'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After august 2016. Azure powershell had breaking changes apparently.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/

The correct way to retrieve resource group based on tags after Azure powershell verion 3.0 is:

```
(Find-AzureRmResourceGroup -Tag @{ Env="Test" }).Name
```